# Error : CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named '' for entity 'Receipt'. But the class is deleted

Tags: ios, swift, class, core-data, entity

I've created a subclass of NSManagedObject for my entity, but after I've deleted it because I don't use it, I just have the entity specified in my xcdatamodeld file.
And when I use this entity, I now get this message in my console : CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named '' for entity 'Receipt'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead. !

How can I completely delete this class so that Core Data do not more research a class for my entity ?

Answer (score 7):

You most likely still have your model trying to access the class.

Go into your XCDataModel and make sure the "classname" for all of your entities is set to `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: If you come across this error then this answer will save your ass.

Comment: This is the right answer for me, coding on Swift 3 and XCode 8